# Select2 un-select any option

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2, but i can not re-select selected item, so what i am doing is to clean select2 drop down menu when any item is selecting, is their any better solution ?

```
$('#selectBox').select2('destroy').val('').select2();
```

Comment: You want unselect all selected option  ? Can you clarify whats the expected output here ?

Comment: currently i am opening a modal when i select any value from select2 drop down, but if i select the value again it do not open modal, if i select the pre-selected value it should pop modal again,

Comment: You  simply mean that when you open modal you select value and when you close modal you want to unselect all the option you selected. And when you open again you start again ? Like you want to reset the select2 value each time you close the modal ?

Comment: yes, you got it man

Comment: how many select box boxes you have just one or multiple ?

Comment: i have only 1 select2 box, with id selectBox as mentioned in question

Comment: In your modal close function Just add this - `$("#selectBox").val('').change();` - this will reset the select2 value to `null` on close. This should work let me know if you want me to post as `answer` so you can `accept` if you wish to! Thanks.

Comment: okey, and how to handle the situation if user clicks out side the modal (modal auto hides in that case,)

Comment: Did my answer helped you ?

Comment: Glad to help. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this `val()` and select to null with an `change` function to reset your select2 seelected value when you click close

User clicks close button add this in your close function:

```
$("#selectBox").val('').change();
```

If user click outside the modal (Auto hide) Use this code:

```
$(document).click(function() {
   $("#selectBox").val('').change();
}
```